# How to Inset irregular (unevenly scaled) shapes?

Tags: extrude, scale

To start: I'm an amateur and only using Blender for this one thing. I've learned everything from videos, forums, or just tinkering so I don't know a lot of the terms. I did apply scale though so that's not the problem.

I'm trying to create 3D numbers that extrude a bit, then inset the remainder of their depth as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPsMr.jpg). I've created SVGs and for the "1" I just extruded twice and manually moved the lowest vertices inward and it created exactly what I wanted. However, with most every other number this doesn't work and I've tried a few methods:

[Inset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edm10.jpg)

[Scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Hkn.jpg) (and [scaling individual parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MABOx.jpg))

And I don't want to [move every vertex individually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXSD5.jpg) because there's so damn many plus it's impossible to get even remotely clean.

One thing I noticed was the problem with Inset is it creates a mess where the crosshatch-y things overlap and extend past the original shape boundaries (seen in the Inset link). Is there a way to remove the protrusions or contain it within the number shape? Or is there just a way to get irregular shapes that don't scale evenly to inset?

Comment: please edit your post in order to show the pictures here  ;)

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in uploader when adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: The links are to gifs hosted on Imgur because I could not use the built-in uploader due to the files being too large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how it evaded me the past multiple searches, but I've discovered the solution! Blender 2.8 comes with the Inset Straight Skeleton add-on bundled. Add it under Preferences>Add-Ons>Mesh>Inset Straight Skeleton. It's accessed by searching (F3) and has only two parameters: Amount and Height. Using this I was able to accomplish exactly what I wanted! Hope this helps others in the future!

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screencap]

Comment: Oh, what a great tool, thanks for sharing :). It can be then found in *Face > Inset Straight Skeleton*. And a [Blender Manual page is here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/mesh/inset_straight_skeleton.html).

Comment: If you need to inset it further and it's doing that overlapping clipping, you can Select>All By Trait>Non Manifold and delete faces and it creates a clean shape.